# can't connect to mysql in docker from bash

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

I am able to access mysql via workbench with hostname: localhost and port: 3306 which were present by default, but I can't connect it via bash

`mysql -u root -p`
returns follwing error:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

How to connect mysql in docker via bash?

Comment: Does it work if you specify the hostname? `mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p`?

Comment: yes, it worked. Accessing through host didn't came across my mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `-h` arugument:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

The error message tells you that `mysql` tried to connect to the unix socket `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and not to the network socket.